# Как сделать в Unity2D чтобы текстура повторялась?

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать чтобы 2Д текстура не просто накладывалась и растягивалась, а повторялась?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fI8t.gif

Comment: Ещё в настройках текстуры `Wrap Mode: Repeat`! Но она всё равно будет и накладываться и растягиваться =D

Comment: Дак как сделать чтобы повторялась?